# django msg.send() not working as it should

Tags: python, django

when i send mail through django view (code below):

```
subject = "Audit report for all staff  "    
email_msg = "Hello Everyone," + '\n \n' + subject + '\n \n' + 'Thanks \n-Admin'
report_name = response['Content-Disposition'].split('=')[1]

msg = EmailMessage(
            subject = subject,
            body = email_msg,
            attachments=(('%s' % report_name,f.read(), 'text/csv'),),
            to = ['prateekm@localhost','prateek@gmail.com' ],
       )
    msg.send()
```

My mail is only being sent  to the localhost email id and not to the gmail id . How to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Django does not automatically send to remote servers. It does it through SMTP backend. You need to configure it.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/#e-mail-backends

Answer (score 0):

For configuring SMTP server, u have to give something like this in your settings.py [provided SMTP is installed]

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "xxx@gmail.com" #create a gmail id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxxx"#pwd for that id
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: can using these settings i can mail to different mail ids like yahoo,rediff,gmail e.t.c